# Is there a way to list all the rpms in an iso image?

Tags: linux

I need a way to list all the RPMS in an iso image without booting the iso file and making a live image. Eventually I'm trying to make a very light weight cron job or Jenkins jobs to get the list of RPMS on an iso image.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Note : There are no rpm packages on a live DVD, cd image.iso

Answer (score 0):

```
mount -o loop your.iso /mnt/cd
find /mnt/cd -type f -name '*.rpm' | wc -l
unmount /mnt/cd
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want the list of rpm's that were used to construct the iso.

If the ISO contains an rpmdb, you can mount the ISO, and then run

```
rpm -qa --dbpath /path/to/iso/mount/var/lib/rpm
```

Watch out for lock creation (if run as root and/or the ISO rpmdb directory is "writable" somehow).

The simplest way to avoid rpmdb lock creation is to run the query as non-root: rpm queries will run without creating locks if the rpmdb directory is unwritable.